# Communication Link Failure mySQL NetBeans

Tags: mysql, connection, mysql-error-1064

Hi everybody I'm new and I'm having some trouble with a connection with netbeans and mysql, I need a database online I created one at 000webhost.com but I think that something's wrong .... if any have some idea or other server I really need to connect a database from a server online with an app in netbeans.

Here is my configuration:

[image]

If you have any ideas to connect any database like sql server or postgres or mysql with a database online but works please tell me, I need some idea or some HowTo.

Comment: [Connect to an online MySQL database from localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083177/connect-to-an-online-mysql-database-from-localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first screenshot (the second screenshot doesn't load for me) it looks correct. If you have double checked all the details provided you will have to contact your hosting provider. If it were a problem with NetBeans or the driver itself you would get a different error.

Make sure you copy details from an email rather than retype them to prevent mixing up things like 0 and O. Also be sure when your copy the text you don't catch extra spaces or hidden tabs.

Comment: the hosting provider is a free web hosting I don't know if any web hosting can provide connection to my sql because somebody tell me this : mySQL servers usually provide connection only for localhost or a local subnet for security reasons